# Error when calling send method in Codeigniter email library

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

Edited:
Im trying to send an email using codeigniter's library. Whenever I call the $this->email->send() function it returns

> Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\psems\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\psems\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\psems\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\psems\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269

This is the code I have so far

```
 $config = array();
    $config['useragent']           = "CodeIgniter";
    $config['mailpath']            = "/usr/bin/sendmail"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
    $config['protocol']            = "smtp";
    $config['smtp_host']           = "localhost";
    $config['smtp_port']           = "25";
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
    $config['newline']  = "\r\n";
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->from('example@gmail.com', 'harold decapia');
    $this->email->to('example@gmail.com');

    $this->email->subject('Тест Email');
    $this->email->message('Hello World');

    $this->email->send(); //I tried commenting this out and there was no error returned
```

I'm confused as to why it returns an error just by calling the send method. Do I have to configure something first? I'm thinking I'm missing a tiny bit of info here :(

Also, is there any way for me to know what error it returns specifically? Thank you in advance

Comment: try echo $this->email->print_debugger();

Comment: tried that and it said "The following SMTP error was encountered: 10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
"

Comment: have you tried php mailer lib for smtp

Comment: not yet. i actually have that in mind but i want this to work :(

Answer (score 0):

The error as far as I can see it's coming because you're trying to send an email with SMTP on a server without and actual FTP server (Happens a lot with local servers).

I'm going to suggest a free service like [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) to use as an SMTP server while you're developing.

Also if you're going to use SMTP protocol, you'll need to use an User and Password to authenticate on the SMTP server (Mailgun will provide you with that too).

Here it's a sample of the new configurations for the SMTP server/authentication, remember you need to adjust to the information the Mailgun website will give you on your account.

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.mailgun.org';
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '30';
$config['smtp_user'] = 'postmaster@mydomain.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
```

:)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I still cannot send though. I already have the user and password credentials from Mailgun. But as I run my code it says "Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535 5.7.0 Business Verification 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method." I'm thinking it has something to do with my password being incorrectly typed orsomething but I just copied and pasted it. I dont know why it returns a failure inpassword authentication :(

Comment: @HaroldDecapia check on mailgun dashboard again to see if the password hasn't changed for some weird reason.